# JQuery Validation - Checkbox validation not posting all values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I'm having problems with some checkbox validation.
I'm using the plugin validation for this: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I have three checkboxes and at least one must be ticked. My initial form code for these checkboxes are:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options" value="News">News
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options" value="Events">Events
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options" value="Promotions">Promotions
```

The validation rules are:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
            rules: {
                email_options_name: {
                    required: true
                },
                email_options_company: {
                    required: true
                },
                email_options_country: {
                    required: true
                },
                email_option_email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                check_options: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
              }
            },      
        });
```

The validation here for check_options works fine. However the php script which processes the form will only print the value of the last check box (so if two or three were ticked only the last value is posted).

I revised my input names to fix this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options[]" value="News">News
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options[]" value="Events">Events
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options[]" value="Promotions">Promotions
```

This shows all of the values in the post. However I can't get the validation to work for it. If I put in my rules:

```
check_options[]: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1
          }
```

I get an Javascript error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id

If i leave it without the square brackets the validation doesn't happen.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options[]" value="News" required minlength="1">News
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options[]" value="Events">Events
<input type="checkbox" checked name="check_options[]" value="Promotions">Promotions
```

and the javascript-

```
 check_options: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
      }
```

Comment: You can also just quote your name in the javascript `'check_options[]'` would work.